# When the 'wrong' answer is accepted

Tags: discussion

I'm using [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/why-isnt-the-cross-considered-an-idol) as an example but it applies to others.

The currently accepted answer to this question is a statement if a tiny minority viewpoint, one that I doubt is accepted by more than 2-3% of Christians. However it's been accepted, and I would venture to suggest it is accepted because it is the viewpoint of the questioner.

If this site has any pretensions to be a reference site, this is clearly not a desirable state of affairs. The accepted answer comes to the top, and it looks as though we are endorsing a fringe view. Better, more comprehensive, answers exist and have more votes.

Any suggestions as to whether we want to do something about this, and if so what

Answer (score 2):

Remember that there are no guidelines on what constitutes and "accepted" answer beyond "It is the answer most useful to the questioner"

Ultimately the check mark from the accepted answer means that for the person who asked the question it is the correct answer.

If you disagree with the response or the answer is incorrect you have votes too, this just gives the person asking the question a bit more say so as to which answer was the most useful to them.

Comment: I agree. This type of situation is unavoidable on a site that is so loose in it's definition of what is a Christian. The open, accepting nature of the site pretty much guarantees that in any answer, someone will consider it "wrong". Besides, how else is anyone supposed to earn the "populist" badge?

Comment: The same situation comes up on the more technical SE sites as well, where an answer meets the questioner's needs and is accpeted, and a much better one comes along later.

Answer (score 0):

We probably ought to Vote to Close that question seeming as it's one of those Jehovah's Witnesses vs Mainline Protestants vs Catholics sort of questions.

I'd figure it would be most appropriate for Catholics to answer since we had to deal with iconoclasts and must have some sort of argument about it. But since he's asking about a cross and not a crucifix maybe it's in the domain of Protestantism?  In any event, he certainly isn't asking about Jehovah's Witness rationale for not doing something, not sure why that'd be the answer.  It's not like he asked a question about sorting algorithms and someone just said, "Use Merge Sort".